# If size() method of ArrayList returns a number which is too big to be stored in an int how will Java store it

Tags: java, arraylist, size

Lets assume that there is a variable "x" of type int. If size()  method of ArrayList returns a number which is too big to be stored in an int how will Java store it. Will there be upcasting of int to double or will there be some exception.

Comment: Arrays are `int` indexed in Java. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: For a learner it does make sense.

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayList#size()` cannot return a number bigger than what fits in an `int`. For one, an `ArrayList` is backed by an array which can only contain `Integer.MAX_VALUE` number of elements. Second, and more importantly, the method's return type is `int`. It can only return `int` values.